# What are the details of the recent agreement between Sony Pictures and Marvel Studios?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-amazing-spider-man

It was recently announced that Sony Pictures and Marvel Studios have come to an agreement whereby each of them will share the film rights to the characters relating to Spider-man.

What are the details of this agreement, as in, who has creative control, distribution rights, and how can each party use the character? Additionally, what is currently known about the future of The Amazing Spider-man franchise?

Comment: There's a great Variety article that I think addresses all of this: http://variety.com/2015/film/news/spider-man-marvel-sony-movies-1201429508/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would have to happen to merge the Spider-man franchise and the Avengers franchise?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/what-would-have-to-happen-to-merge-the-spider-man-franchise-and-the-avengers-fra)

Comment: @Pureferret If this is a dup, can I just move my answer over there?... I mean, not that it took much work. Though, now that it's actually come to pass, the question isn't hypothetical any more, it's factual.

Comment: @Catija and i have done reverse of it :D

Comment: @Pureferret or better approach will be to merge them. Flagged for merger.

Comment: @Pureferret I don't think this needs closing - if anything, the older question is now out-of-date, as it is asking a question which is no longer applicable or relevant. This, however, is based on an event we know has occured, and is seeking further clarification on that agreement.

Comment: I'd also think that this question might deserve to stand on its own. While one could write a fitting answer to the old more hypothetical question (as was done already, I see), I still think this question here poses another more specific question. But I'm not sure either.

Comment: Even though the [official press release](http://marvel.com/news/movies/24062/sony_pictures_entertainment_brings_marvel_studios_into_the_amazing_world_of_spider-man) says `Sony Pictures will [...] have final creative control of the Spider-Man films` I'd say one has to wait and see what that actually means. With Spider-Man becoming part of the MCU Marvel will certainly not give Sony the free means to fuck up their universe, especially since they are `exploring opportunities to integrate characters from the MCU into future Spider-Man films`.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - this is probably the trickiest merge request I've been asked to make, but I tend to agree that this question can stand on its own.  The other question is more hypothetical, and could go further into what would be required to merge the franchises in terms of cast, storylines etc.

Comment: @Oliver_C i am more happy if sony get lesser control. They already damaged the franchise, i think Disney can handle it better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Variety's article, *[Spiderman Returns to Marvel; New Movie Coming in 2017](http://variety.com/2015/film/news/spider-man-marvel-sony-movies-1201429508/)*:

**Who has creative control, distribution rights?**

> Sony will continue to distribute, finance, own and have final creative control of the Spider-Man pics.

**How can each party use the character?**

> They’ll work with Marvel, owned by Disney, on how to weave Spider-Man’s character into Marvel’s upcoming superhero films, which includes the popular franchise “The Avengers.”
>
> As Variety previously reported, Marvel plans on bringing the Civil War storyline from the comic books to launch the next phase of films. It’s very likely that Spider-Man will make his first appearance in *Captain America: Civil War* next year.

**What is currently known about the future of The Amazing Spiderman franchise?**

> According to the announcement, Sony and Marvel will cast a new Spider-Man after Andrew Garfield starred in the last two films, *The Amazing Spider-Man* and *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*. Tobey Maguire played Peter Parker in the previous three installments for Sony.